# Make exponent style in Riche Text field

Tags: redactor, plugin-redactorstyles

I want to provide an easy way to make exponent style text in the Redactor field type.
[image]

**Is there a Redactor plugin to do that?**

If no what is the best way to handle that?

1/ HTML superscript tag

`<p>This text contains <sup>superscript</sup> text.</p>`

or
2/ CSS custom Redactor class

```
.sup { 
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive and most simple answer for all Redactor Inline Styles requests is this great plugin from carlcs:
https://github.com/carlcs/craft-redactorinlinestyles

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In `craft/config/redactor` you can either add your own setting file, or edit one of the ones already there. If you add the following JSON:

```
"formattingAdd": [
  {
    "tag": "sup",
    "title": "Superscript"
  }
]
```

You will have access to a `Superscript` choice under the `Formatting` buttons dropdown menu. This will wrap the selected text in a `<sup>` tag.

While I'm not sure if this is the correct way of adding stuff like this, I just tested it and it does work.